# How to documenting an argument object's function definition

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, jsdoc

How can I document a class's argument, when that argument is a property which contains a property which is a function (whoah).

Example:

```
class MyClass {
    /**
     * @param {Object} options - configuration for the class
     * @param {Function} options.onSuccess - a callback function which has two arguments A and B
     * @memberof MyClass
     */
    constructor(options) {...}
}
```

How can I define that someone should use this class like this, where onSuccess passes two arguments, A and B (where A might be an object with other properties, etc.)

```
var instance = new MyClass({
    onSuccess: (A, B) => {...}
});
```

I'm using Visual Studio Code and it's showing no definition found. Is this possible or is it too many levels deep?

Comment: Did my answer help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the types for `a` and `b` are, or whether the function returns `void`. But here are some options:

```
interface MyClassArgs {
    onSuccess: (a, b) => void;
}

class MyClass {
    constructor(options: MyClassArgs) { }
}
```

Or

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(options: { onSuccess: (a, b) => void }) { }
}
```